# SmartGWT and GWT upgrades not refreshed after upgrading jar versions

Tags: maven, gwt, smartgwt

I have an opensource project in GitHub that I am working on with lots of changes, etc.  I recently upgrade the maven pom file to use the lastest Spring Release (from 3.1 to 3.2.3).  I also upgrade from GWT 2.5 to 2.5.1, and finally from SmartGWT 2.5 to 4.0.  After some minor code changes, I was ready to test this.

I can tell you that the Maven code builds successfully, STS/Eclipse report no errors.  I can build run the app with no problems.  The issue stems from when I run the app, the text boxes cannot have data entered into them, and the link items appear as text boxes.

After doing some research on the SMartGWT forums, I see that the browser cache needs to be cleared which I have done several times.  I deleted my entire target directory which also deleted any gwt generated classes, code, ui, nocache.js, etc.   I can re-run the maven build which re-creates everything.  Again, I can clear my cache, and still the problem happens.

UPDATED:
I created a new SmartGWT 4.0 and GWT 2.5.1 project from scratch.  I created a new login screen, I added small bits of code at a time, and watched to see what would happen, would it work or not.  It broke when I got to adding all the DynamicForm attributes.   Adding the datasource at this time is what broke my login form.  I agree there really is no reason to bind this to the datasource at this time.  In the onClick of the Submit button, I call the loginDS.fetch(criteria) manually.

So, that would be my advice to anyone working with SmartGWT, if something doesn't work, just start re-adding stuff back slowly, and keep testing until you narrow down exactly what is causing the form/screen to not work.    I hope this helps other people!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I basically just followed my own advice above as well.

I just took the broken widget and re-created a new version, and slowly moved over one method at a ime until I found the broken code.  I fixed that piece, and everything worked.

The actual broken code was that  I was tying the datasource to my form, and I didn't need to do that in my situation.

Answer (score 0):

Check in Eclipse for the project settings, make sure you have the right versions selected for the libraries. For example, the GWT SDK is under Google>Web Toolkit.

Comment: Yep, that is correctly showing GWT SDK 2.5.1.  The Java Build Path is also showing the right GWT 2.5.1 Library.   Maven is also showing the smartgwt4.0.jar and the correct GWT jars.  The Java Build Path is also showing that we want to include ALL the files, and exclude nothing.   That way when we look at the Google Web settings, we pulled in the correct GWT Module.

Comment: I basically just followed my own advice above as well.   I just took the broken widget and re-created a new version, and slowly moved over one method at a ime until I found the broken code.  I fixed that piece, and everything worked.    The actual broken code was that  I was tying the datasource to my form, and I didn't need to do that in my situation.